# Board generator for a Food Chain Magnate implementation

Tags: java

I'm implementing the logic of a board game in Java to practice my coding skills. I chose [Food Chain Magnate](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/175914/food-chain-magnate) because is a fairly complex game that requires different data structures. One of my first tasks is to generate the data structure for the game board. In the game, the board is built using some (of all, depending of the # of players) of the 20 available tiles. Each tile is a grid of 5 x 5 squares. The identity of each tile is not important during the game, only if some square is in a different tile than another.

I created a `Board` class that is basically a wrapper over a 2D Object array with additional methods for calculation, and a `BoardGenerator` that create `Board`s and initializes it with the contents of the different tiles.

**Board.java**

```
package com.lartkma.fcm.model.board;

public class Board {
    
    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 5;
    public static final Object OFF_LIMIT = new Object();
    
    private Object[][] boardSquares;
    
    public Board(int widthTiles, int heightTiles) {
        this.boardSquares = new Object[widthTiles * TILE_SIZE][heightTiles * TILE_SIZE];
    }
    
    public Object get(int x, int y) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < this.boardSquares.length && y >= 0 && y < this.boardSquares[0].length) {
            return this.boardSquares[x][y];
        } else {
            return OFF_LIMIT;
        }
    }
    
    public Object get(Point p) {
        return get(p.x(), p.y());
    }
    
    public void set(int x, int y, Object obj) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < this.boardSquares.length && y >= 0 && y < this.boardSquares[0].length) {
            this.boardSquares[x][y] = obj;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Point " + new Point(x, y) + " is out of the board");
        }
    }
    
    public void set(Point p, Object obj) {
        set(p.x(), p.y(), obj);
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return this.boardSquares.length;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return this.boardSquares[0].length;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the tile where the square belongs, relative to this board. The value
     * is not related to the original tile used to build the board, only allows to
     * differentiate one tile from another.
     * @param p
     * @return
     */
    public int getTileNumber(Point p) {
        return (p.y() / TILE_SIZE) * (this.boardSquares.length / TILE_SIZE) + (p.x() / TILE_SIZE);
    }

}
```

The `Point` class is a simple, immutable 2D point class with a constructor `Point(int x, int y)`, methods `x()`, `y()` for retrieval and a `add(int dx, int dy)` method that returns the point (x + dx, y + dy). I'm not writing it here to focus in the other classes.

**BoardGenerator.java**

```
package com.lartkma.fcm.model.board;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BoardGenerator {

    public static Board fromRandom(int widthTiles, int heightTiles) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Map<Character, Object[][]> tileList = getTileList();
        List<Character> randomTiles = new LinkedList<>(tileList.keySet());
        Collections.shuffle(randomTiles);

        Board board = new Board(widthTiles, heightTiles);
        for (int i = 0; i < widthTiles; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < heightTiles; j++) {
                fillWithTile(board, tileList.get(randomTiles.get(i * heightTiles + j)), i * Board.TILE_SIZE,
                        j * Board.TILE_SIZE, rnd.nextInt(4));
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a board using the tiles and rotations indicated in the expression.
     * 
     * The expression is composed of (# tiles tall) subexpressions separated by
     * newlines or spaces, each subexpression made of (# tiles wide x 2) characters.
     * 
     * Each 2 characters of a subexpression describe a tile and the rotation of such
     * tile. The tile is indicated with one of the upper-case characters used in
     * <a href="https://boardgamehelpers.com/FoodChainMagnate/MapTileKey.aspx">this page</a>.
     * The rotation is described as a digit from 1 to 4, where 1 is the orientation shown in
     * the page mentioned above (with the identified in the bottom left), 2 rotates the
     * reference orientation rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and so on.
     * 
     * @param expression
     * @return
     */
    public static Board fromExpression(String expression) {
        String[] rows = expression.split("\n|\r\n| ");
        int heightTiles = rows.length;
        int widthTiles = Stream.of(rows).mapToInt(s -> s.length() / 2).max().orElse(0);
        Board board = new Board(widthTiles, heightTiles);
        Map<Character, Object[][]> tileList = getTileList();
        for (int i = 0; i < widthTiles; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < heightTiles; j++) {
                if (2 * i + 1 < rows[rows.length - 1 - j].length()) {
                    char tileId = rows[rows.length - 1 - j].charAt(2 * i);
                    char tileRotationFactor = rows[rows.length - 1 - j].charAt(2 * i + 1);
                    if (tileList.containsKey(tileId) && tileRotationFactor >= '1' && tileRotationFactor <= '4') {
                        // Number of rotations goes from 0 to 3
                        fillWithTile(board, tileList.get(tileId), i * Board.TILE_SIZE, j * Board.TILE_SIZE,
                                tileRotationFactor - '1');
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "Board tile expression \"" + tileId + tileRotationFactor + "\" cannot be read");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    private static Map<Character, Object[][]> getTileList() {
        Map<Character, Object[][]> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(BoardGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream("tiles.txt")))) {
            int lineCount = 1;
            Object[][] currentTileContent = new Object[Board.TILE_SIZE][Board.TILE_SIZE];
            char currentTileIdentifier = 'A';
            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = stream.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Board.TILE_SIZE; i++) {
                    char lineChar = currentLine.charAt(i);
                    if (lineChar == 'O') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = null;
                    } else if (lineChar == '-') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, true, false, true);
                    } else if (lineChar == '|') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, false, true, false);
                    } else if (lineChar == '/') {
                        // check the previous and next squares in the same line to check if this is
                        // a up-to-right turn or a right-to-up turn
                        char previous = (i == 0 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i - 1));
                        char next = (i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i + 1));
                        if ((isHorizontalRoad(previous) || i == 0) && !isHorizontalRoad(next)) {
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, false, false,
                                    true);
                        } else if (!isHorizontalRoad(previous)
                                && (isHorizontalRoad(next) || i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1)) {
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, true, true,
                                    false);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown combination on ( " + currentLine + ")");
                        }
                    } else if (lineChar == '\\') {
                        // check the previous and next squares in the same line to check if this is
                        // a up-to-left turn or a left-to-up turn
                        char previous = (i == 0 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i - 1));
                        char next = (i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i + 1));
                        if ((isHorizontalRoad(previous) || i == 0) && !isHorizontalRoad(next)) {
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, false, true,
                                    true);
                        } else if (!isHorizontalRoad(previous)
                                && (isHorizontalRoad(next) || i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1)) {
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, true, false,
                                    false);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown combination on ( " + currentLine + ")");
                        }
                    } else if (lineChar == '^') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, true, false, true);
                    } else if (lineChar == '>') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, true, true, false);
                    } else if (lineChar == 'V') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, true, true, true);
                    } else if (lineChar == '<') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, false, true, true);
                    } else if (lineChar == '+') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, true, true, true);
                    } else if (lineChar == 'S') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = GoodsSource.SODA;
                    } else if (lineChar == 'B') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = GoodsSource.BEER;
                    } else if (lineChar == 'L') {
                        currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = GoodsSource.LEMONADE;
                    } else if (lineChar >= '0' && lineChar <= '9') {
                        Object previous = (i == 0 ? null : currentTileContent[i - 1][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount]);
                        if (previous instanceof House) {
                            // part of a two-digit house, same entity as left
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE
                                    - lineCount] = currentTileContent[i - 1][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount];
                        } else {
                            int houseOrder = (lineChar - '0'); // classic
                            char next = (i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i + 1));
                            if (next >= '0' && next <= '9') { // two digit id
                                houseOrder = houseOrder * 10 + (next - '0');
                            }
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new House(houseOrder);
                        }
                    } else if (lineChar == 'H') {
                        Object previous = (i == 0 ? null : currentTileContent[i - 1][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount]);
                        if (previous instanceof House) {
                            // same entity as left
                            currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = previous;
                        } else {
                            previous = (lineCount == 1 ? null
                                    : currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount + 1]);
                            if (previous instanceof House) {
                                // same entity as up
                                currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = previous;
                            } else {
                                throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Unknown combination on ( " + currentLine + "): no house defined near H");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown symbol: " + lineChar);
                    }
                }

                lineCount += 1;
                if (lineCount > Board.TILE_SIZE) {
                    outputMap.put(currentTileIdentifier, currentTileContent);
                    lineCount = 1;
                    currentTileContent = new Object[Board.TILE_SIZE][Board.TILE_SIZE];
                    currentTileIdentifier += 1;
                }
            }

            return outputMap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("tiles.txt not available", e);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isHorizontalRoad(char c) {
        return c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '\\' || c == '^' || c == 'V' || c == '+';
    }

    private static void fillWithTile(Board board, Object[][] tileArray, int xStart, int yStart, int numRotations) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Board.TILE_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board.TILE_SIZE; j++) {
                Point boardPoint = new Point(xStart + i, yStart + j);
                Point tileCoords = toTileCoords(i, j, numRotations);
                Object inTile = tileArray[tileCoords.x()][tileCoords.y()];
                if (inTile instanceof House) {
                    Object prevHouse;
                    if ((prevHouse = board.get(boardPoint.add(-1, 0))) instanceof House
                            && ((House) prevHouse).getOrder() == ((House) inTile).getOrder()) {
                        // check house at the left
                        board.set(boardPoint, prevHouse);
                    } else if ((prevHouse = board.get(boardPoint.add(0, -1))) instanceof House
                            && ((House) prevHouse).getOrder() == ((House) inTile).getOrder()) {
                        // check house below
                        board.set(boardPoint, prevHouse);
                    } else {
                        board.set(boardPoint, new House(((House) inTile).getOrder()));
                    }
                } else if (inTile instanceof Road) {
                    board.set(boardPoint, ((Road) inTile).rotate(numRotations));
                } else if (inTile instanceof GoodsSource || inTile == null) {
                    board.set(boardPoint, inTile);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown object: " + inTile.getClass());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Point toTileCoords(int x, int y, int rotations) {
        switch (rotations) {
            case 0:
                return new Point(x, y);
            case 1:
                return new Point(Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 - y, x);
            case 2:
                return new Point(Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 - x, Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 - y);
            case 3:
                return new Point(y, Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 - x);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should not happen");
        }
    }
}
```

The `tiles.txt` file contains the description of the 20 tiles. The contents of each tile can be seen here: https://boardgamehelpers.com/FoodChainMagnate/MapTileKey.aspx (doesn't include the expansion tiles). It's a plain text file formed with lines of 5 characters each. Each 5 lines describes a tile (5 x 5). Each tile is assigned a character as is shown in the reference link, being the first 5 lines tile A, the next 5 tile B and so on. Each character (or group of characters) represents an object. For example, tile E is described as

```
/-/OO
|BOOO
/O8H/
OOHH|
OO/-/
```

(characters `/` and `\` can represent either one of two possible types of turns, depending of context)

**Road.java**

```
package com.lartkma.fcm.model.board;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Road {
    private boolean[] canMove;

    public Road(boolean canGoUp, boolean canGoRight, boolean canGoDown, boolean canGoLeft) {
        this.canMove = new boolean[] { canGoUp, canGoRight, canGoDown, canGoLeft };
    }

    public boolean canMove(Direction inDirection) {
        return this.canMove[inDirection.ordinal()];
    }

    public Road rotate(int amountRotations) {
        Road rotated = new Road(this.canMove[0], this.canMove[1], this.canMove[2], this.canMove[3]);
        if (amountRotations < 0) {
            // Java operator % returns a remainder, that is different from a mathematical
            // modulus
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers
            // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3
            amountRotations = amountRotations % rotated.canMove.length + rotated.canMove.length;
        } else {
            amountRotations = amountRotations % rotated.canMove.length;
        }
        boolean swapTemp;
        for (int k = 0; k < amountRotations; k++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < rotated.canMove.length; i++) { // it makes no sense for the first element
                swapTemp = rotated.canMove[0];
                rotated.canMove[0] = rotated.canMove[i];
                rotated.canMove[i] = swapTemp;
            }
        }
        return rotated;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Road) {
            return Arrays.equals(this.canMove, ((Road) obj).canMove);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner name = new StringJoiner("-", "Road[", "]");
        for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
            if (canMove(d)) {
                name.add(d.name());
            }
        }
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

`Direction` is an enum with values `UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT` (in that order). `House` is a simple data class with a `order` property, but it will mutate other properties during the game. `GoodsSource` is a simple, immutable class that can only have 3 possible instances.

**BoardGeneratorTest.java** (for a sample of how it's used)

```
package com.lartkma.fcm.model.board;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.sameInstance;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.lartkma.fcm.model.board.Board;
import com.lartkma.fcm.model.board.GoodsSource;
import com.lartkma.fcm.model.board.House;
import com.lartkma.fcm.model.board.BoardGenerator;
import com.lartkma.fcm.model.board.Road;

public class BoardGeneratorTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("The board generator can receive specific tiles as parameters and should generate the correct amount of squares")
    public void testBoardGeneratorSizeFromExpression() {
        Board board = BoardGenerator.fromExpression("G1E2\nI3M4");
        assertAll("The board should be of 2 x 2 tiles (10 x 10 squares)",
                () -> assertEquals(10, board.getWidth(), "Board width"),
                () -> assertEquals(10, board.getHeight(), "Board height"));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("The board generator can generate a random board and should generate the correct amount of squares")
    public void testBoardGeneratorSizeFromRandom() {
        Board board = BoardGenerator.fromRandom(3, 2);
        assertAll("The board should be of 3 x 2 tiles (15 x 10 squares)",
                () -> assertEquals(15, board.getWidth(), "Board width"),
                () -> assertEquals(10, board.getHeight(), "Board height"));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("The board generator can create a 1-tile board with the correct contents")
    public void testBoardGeneratorContent() {
        Board board = BoardGenerator.fromExpression("E1");
        assertAll("The board should have the following contents",
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 0", board.get(0, 0), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 0", board.get(1, 0), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 0", board.get(2, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 0", board.get(3, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 0", board.get(4, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 1", board.get(0, 1), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 1", board.get(1, 1), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 1", board.get(2, 1), is(equalTo(new House(8)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 1", board.get(3, 1), is(sameInstance(board.get(2, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 1", board.get(4, 1), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 2", board.get(0, 2), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 2", board.get(1, 2), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 2", board.get(2, 2), is(sameInstance(board.get(2, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 2", board.get(3, 2), is(sameInstance(board.get(2, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 2", board.get(4, 2), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 3", board.get(0, 3), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 3", board.get(1, 3), is(equalTo(GoodsSource.BEER))),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 3", board.get(2, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 3", board.get(3, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 3", board.get(4, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 4", board.get(0, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 4", board.get(1, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 4", board.get(2, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 4", board.get(3, 4), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 4", board.get(4, 4), is(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("The board generator can create a rotated 1-tile board with the correct contents")
    public void testBoardGeneratorContentRotated() {
        Board board = BoardGenerator.fromExpression("E2");
        assertAll("The board should have the following contents",
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 0", board.get(0, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(true, true, false, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 0", board.get(1, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 0", board.get(2, 0), is(equalTo(new Road(false, false, true, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 0", board.get(3, 0), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 0", board.get(4, 0), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 1", board.get(0, 1), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 1", board.get(1, 1), is(equalTo(new House(8)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 1", board.get(2, 1), is(sameInstance(board.get(1, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 1", board.get(3, 1), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 1", board.get(4, 1), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 2", board.get(0, 2), is(equalTo(new Road(false, false, true, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 2", board.get(1, 2), is(sameInstance(board.get(1, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 2", board.get(2, 2), is(sameInstance(board.get(1, 1)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 2", board.get(3, 2), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 2", board.get(4, 2), is(equalTo(new Road(true, true, false, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 3", board.get(0, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 3", board.get(1, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 3", board.get(2, 3), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 3", board.get(3, 3), is(equalTo(GoodsSource.BEER))),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 3", board.get(4, 3), is(equalTo(new Road(true, false, true, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 0, 4", board.get(0, 4), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 1, 4", board.get(1, 4), is(nullValue())),
                () -> assertThat("In 2, 4", board.get(2, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(true, true, false, false)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 3, 4", board.get(3, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(false, true, false, true)))),
                () -> assertThat("In 4, 4", board.get(4, 4), is(equalTo(new Road(false, false, true, true)))));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final int TILE_SIZE = 5;
```

Maybe call this `TILE_EDGE_SIZE` or something similar, as a tile doesn't contain 5 squares.

```
public Object get(int x, int y) {
```

Remove this, just use `get(Point p)`, it's not that more work.

```
return OFF_LIMIT;
```

This single *magic value* is keeping you from using the correct class for the Array. Magic values are something you might want to avoid. If you really want to avoid an exception, use `Optional<Square>`. But personally I would throw an exception and use `Optional` instead of returning `null`.

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Point " + new Point(x, y) + " is out of the board");
```

I knew you could do it, now make the methods *symmetric* on how they handle out of bounds.

```
public int getWidth() {
...
public int getHeight() {
```

Perfect, no reason why the application would ever return `OFF_LIMIT` then.

---

```
Map<Character, Object[][]> tileList = getTileList();
```

Mixing collections and arrays is not a good idea; just use collections.

```
List<Character> randomTiles = new LinkedList<>(tileList.keySet());
```

To be precise, you'd use `ArrayList` here, not a linked list.

```
Collections.shuffle(randomTiles);
```

Because looking up random indexes and then moving them around in a linked list is just not a good idea.

```
fillWithTile(board, tileList.get(randomTiles.get(i * heightTiles + j)), i * Board.TILE_SIZE, j * Board.TILE_SIZE, rnd.nextInt(4));
```

Way too much is going on in this method, split it out. Why is this happening and what is it doing? Why is there a magic `4` in there, 4 of what?

```
if (2 * i + 1 < rows[rows.length - 1 - j].length()) {
```

Again, from here we can see how things are being done, but not what or why. The helpful (if incomplete) JavaDoc does help somewhat, but a comment would be appreciated.

```
private static Map<Character, Object[][]> getTileList() {
```

Way too much is being done in this method, the amount of complexity is astounding.

```
if (lineChar == 'O') { // ... endless else if's
```

Here a switch would do wonders, but don't forget the `break;` statements.

```
currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = null;
```

What about `Object tileContent;` declaration, then set it in the `switch`, and in the end assign it to `currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount]`. Too much copy / paste if you ask me.

```
 currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, true, false, true);
```

Ah, a road that goes `false, true, false, true`. That's not a `true` road, use `enum` instead of boolean parameters. It's in Effective Java, which you should read.

```
 EnumSet<Direction> possibleDirections = EnumSet.of(Direction.RIGHT, Direction.LEFT);
```

is just soooo much nicer, don't you agree?

```
char previous = (i == 0 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i - 1));
char next = (i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1 ? 'O' : currentLine.charAt(i + 1));
if ((isHorizontalRoad(previous) || i == 0) && !isHorizontalRoad(next)) {
    currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(true, false, false,
            true);
} else if (!isHorizontalRoad(previous)
        && (isHorizontalRoad(next) || i == Board.TILE_SIZE - 1)) {
    currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = new Road(false, true, true,
            false);
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown combination on ( " + currentLine + ")");
}
```

One value is returned: a `Road`. Method maybe? So easy to distinguish.

```
currentTileContent[i][Board.TILE_SIZE - lineCount] = GoodsSource.SODA;
```

Ah, now I get it. A `Road`, `GoodsSource` a `House` or nothing is expected. Still, create a marker interface such as `TileContent` at the very least, and have `Road` and `GoodsSource` implement it so you don't need `Object`, because that's too ugly.

```
throw new Error("tiles.txt not available", e);
```

Not fully readable is maybe a better exception. `RuntimeException`should be preferred over `Error` which is commonly not recoverable *system wide*.

```
} else if ((prevHouse = board.get(boardPoint.add(0, -1))) instanceof House
        && ((House) prevHouse).getOrder() == ((House) inTile).getOrder()) {
    // check house below
    board.set(boardPoint, prevHouse);
```

OK, so you are creating larger houses. I think I can be mean and create a house that's made up of separate parts. I hope that your houses are square :) But really, again, provide methods.

Enum values can be directly compared, no need to compare `order` for equality.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should not happen");
```

I agree there, such an exception is not acceptable.

```
    return this.canMove[inDirection.ordinal()];
```

Or `possibleDirections.contains(inDirection)` (see above?)